# Converting Coordinates formatted as Lat 4531.38153 Long 12347.2328 to Decimal Degrees?

Tags: coordinate-system, garmin

I've inherited some 20 year old waypoint data that was taken with a Garmin GPS. I don't recognize the lat/lon coordinates as DMS, decimal minutes, or decimal degrees. Here's one record as an example: Lat 4531.38153 Long 12347.2328. I know the very general location of this record to be Lat 45 degrees, Lon -123 degrees.

Can somebody tell me the format of these coordinates so I can convert to decimal degrees?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They look like Degrees Decimal Minutes (DDM) with the degree and minutes symbols dropped.

Try reading `Lat 4531.38153 Long 12347.2328` as `Lat 45° 31.38153' Long 123° 47.2328'`

You may find this [PGC Coordinate Converter](https://www.pgc.umn.edu/apps/convert/) useful.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose it might be NMEA. It has quite strange coordinates representation: lat is DDMM.MMMMM and lon is DDDMM.MMMMM.